# Javascript onclick change button text for a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to change the text on a button to processing for a few seconds when it is click

```
<div id="send"></div>

<button id="button">Send</button>

 <script> 
     $(document).on("click", "#button", function() {   
  var Path = $('#send').html();           
  var success = function() { alert("Successful"); };     
  var error = function(message) { alert("Oopsie! " + message); };  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#send').html("processing")`?

Comment: Can you show better sample code? The code you have right now doesn't do any of the processing you're talking about. Is there asynchronous operations happening you'd like to wait for, or do you really want to show different button text for some arbitrary amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to do this `$('#button').html("Processing");`

Then in the success and error functions, you'll probably want to modify the button text to something else so that it no longer displays "Processing".

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are probably looking for:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function() {  

    var defaultBtnValue = $('#send').html();
    $('#send').html("Processing..."); 

    $.ajax({
       url: your_url,
       type: "GET",
       success: function() {
           alert("Successful");
       },
       error: function(message) {
           alert("Oopsie! " + message);
       },
       complete: function() {
           $('#send').html(defaultBtnValue);
       }
    });
});
```

I'm assuming you wan't this "Processing" to show while something is.. well, processing, like doing an ajax call (this may be a `setTimeout` function as well). Good practice is to first save the default value of the button and make sure to reset it once an action is complete (succes or not) in case something goes wrong.

Comment: It would be even easier to adopt jQuery's promises and chain the handlers, switching the button text back in the `always()` callback: `$.ajax({...}).done(success).fail(error).always(function() { ... change text back ... });`